# How to sort DevExpress Gallery Control items?

Tags: c#, sql, sorting, devexpress

I am using DevExpress GalleryControl in my library program.
But the problem is I want to sort items in GalleryControl and I dont know how can I do that, I believe that GalleryControl doesn't have a built in feature for sorting items(not really sure tho).

So my program is connected in database(SQL).

So here I want to happen, I want to sort it by alphabetically or by author or by department , to do that I want it to create group for gallery control and the group will contains the item that belong to it.

Can you help me with it?

Check for what I've done:

```
public void LoadBooks(object state)
    {

       GalleryItemGroup group = new GalleryItemGroup();
       galleryControl1.Gallery.Groups.Add(group);
            group.Items.Clear();


            group.Caption = "All books";
            group.CaptionAlignment = GalleryItemGroupCaptionAlignment.Center;


        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            connection.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            //This is arrange by alphabetically but I want to create gallery groups for each letters and the group will contain every items that belongs to it.
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from booktable ORDER BY booktitle";
            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(ds);



            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                byte[] byteBLOBData = (byte[])ds.Rows[i]["bookphoto"];
                var stream = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

                Image bookimages = Image.FromStream(stream);
                string author = ds.Rows[i]["bookauthor"].ToString();
                string title = ds.Rows[i]["booktitle"].ToString();



                    group.Items.Add(new GalleryItem(bookimages, title, author));
                    group.Items[i].HoverImage = group.Items[i].Image;

                }
            }));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

By default, it was sorted by book id which is my primary key in SQL.
Please somebody help me , I'll appreciate any help.

By the way I am new here in Stackoverflow. It's nice to be here.

Comment: I see that you have a DataTable as a datasource. Now, you need sorting. Why don't use the data-aware grid with WinExplorer view instead of GalleryControl? https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16253